# Connect to Google BigQuery using IBM Integration Bus

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ibm-cloud

We have a requirement where we need to connect to Google BigQuery API and perform insert and select operation on the tables.

I found Cloud Connectors in IIB documentation but it has only 'AppConnectRESTRequest node' and 'SalesforceRequest node' . Do we have any connector(i.e. any plugin) which can be used to Connect to Google BigQuery.
This is a migration project from WSO2 ESB to IIB. In WSO2 ESB there was a connector called BigQuery Connector which does the job. Similarly we are looking for a connector in IIB.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think IIB ships with a connector for Google BigQuery, but IIB can connect with any REST API, and it can use any Java class library so two options that immediately spring to mind are:

- Use a RESTRequest node to call the BigQuery REST API
- Use a JavaCompute node to call the Google Java API: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/